# spring security hybrid authentication mechanism using both ldap and jdbc realm

Tags: spring

Is there any facility in spring security for using two different authentication managers for one security http tag.
I need functionality like when the user try to login, first I will check in RDBMS if not success then I will check in LDAP

How can I achieve this theme? Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Just add multiple providers, that is supported out-of-the-box.

Comment: Thanks for you response Deinum. So, according to your answer we can give multiple providers for the same authentication manager. right?

Comment: Thanks man It is working

Comment: Can anyone give the url for doc of this feature? Thanks